# In Laravel, I get old session variables when page is backed

Tags: laravel, session

everyone.
I'm developing a laravel project and I have a problem with session variables.
In a.php, I have a session variable "myid" to set 1.
In this page, I put the session variable to 2.
And went to another page(b.php) that uses session variable "myid".
In the page, the "myid" works correctly. it was 2.
And then I backed a.php by clicking back arrow of browser and get "myid".
but it was 1.
It gets old session value. it seems getting cached value.
I want to get updated value 2.
What's wrong.
Looking for your kind help.
Thanks

In home.php, I put "myid" to 1 and go to a.php.

- a.php

// put session

function setMyId(id) {

$.ajax({

```
url: put_session.php

data: {"myid", id}
```

)}

}

// get session

$(document).ready(function(){

...

$.ajax({

```
url: get_session.php

success: function(data) {

   console.log(data);   // it returns always 1 comes from wherever.

}
```

});

...

});

- put_sessoin.php

session()->put("myid", $request->myid);

- get_sessoin.php

session()->get("myid");

// go to b.php

function goToNext() {

window.location.href = b.php;

}

- b.php

$(document).ready(function(){

...

$.ajax({

```
url: get_session.php

success: function(data) {

   console.log(data);   // it returns new data. works correctly;

}
```

});

...

});

Comment: One more thing. if I change myid in b.php and back to a.php(by clicking browser back), it shows old value not changed one.

Answer (score 0):

***Hi there,***

Please, use the session destroy function of laravel when they are of no use anymore!

```
public function destroy($sessionId) {}
```

The destroy method should remove the data associated with the $sessionId from persistent storage.

```
public function gc($lifetime) {}
```

The gc method should destroy all session data that is older than the given $lifetime, which is a UNIX timestamp. For self-expiring systems like Memcached and Redis, this method may be left empty.

For more deatils: 
[Laravel Documentation on Sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session)

***Thanks!***

Comment: session must be not destroyed. it has to be updated when back by clicking back button.